# Issue with the _index.md file

Tags: blogdown

I am trying to build a website by using the blogdown package.
I have modified the information inside the `_index.md` file in `content/authors/admin` obtaining temporarily the result I want. In `about.md` `author = “admin”`.

[[image: Here is a screenshot of the output]

However once I run `blogdown::serve_site()` I obtain a white page with only my name and surname at the top of the page. Also the menu is maintained but I lose the info in the `_index.md` file.

Any suggestions?